# How to compare varchar column with a numeric value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this code as part of my code in snowflake:

Iff((Expr2)='pol',SumOfMANNLZD, '')

With Expr2= varchar column and SumOfMANNLZD=numeric column

When I run it, I have an error: Numeric value '' is not recognized.

But when I assigned '0' it works just fine. for example

```
 Iff((Expr2)='pol',SumOfMANNLZD, '0')
```

However, I want it to return blank/null. Is there a way to archive this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IFF function's possible outputs should have same data type. SumOfMANNLZD is a numeric column, so Snowflake expects you to return a numeric column as the alternative output. If you are OK to return NULL values, you can put NULL instead of '':

```
with mydata as (
  select 'pol' Expr2, 10 SumOfMANNLZD
  union all
  select 'dummy', 20
)
select Iff(Expr2='pol',SumOfMANNLZD, null) from mydata;
```

Or convert the SumOfMANNLZD to varchar if you want to return '':

```
with mydata as (
  select 'pol' Expr2, 10 SumOfMANNLZD
  union all
  select 'dummy', 20
)
select Iff(Expr2='pol',SumOfMANNLZD::Varchar, '') from mydata;
```

Answer (score 0):

in general if you want to compare a number to a string value you have to cast one or the other to the same type. make your numbers string or your strings to numbers. many languages have this ability.  hopefully yours does.